# Database relationship help (user with varying types and groups)

Tags: sql, database-design

An example would if we had a website about beer.

- We'd have `Users` who may or may not be `Brewers`.
- `Users` who are `Brewers` could additionally be part of a `Brewery`.

Current setup:

```js
// made up shorthand TS like syntax to demonstrate
User {
    role: User | Moderator | Admin; // global site permissions
    type: User | Brewer; // did user register as a brewer?
    brewery: Brewery; // reference the Brewery if user is part of one
    breweryRole: Owner | Member; // reference the Brewery Role is user is part of one
}

Brewery {
    owner: User; // reference user who created the Brewery so they always have permissions
    members: [User]; // list of users who belong to this Brewery
}
```

Essentially we have varying user `types` along with external `groups` that the user may belong to.

I would like to hear feedback on whether or not this is a pattern that should be used. I'd love to see alternatives to this.

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `Brewery.members`.

It's redundant since you already have the `Users.brewery` reference, and you risk the data getting out of sync. I mean, if you find `Brewery.members` lists user 1234, but that user's `Users.brewery` references a different brewery, how can you know which is the correct membership?

One of the best strengths of relational database normalization is that every fact is stored only once, so there's no way it can get out of sync or disagree with other data that represents the same information.